# Pagination Component with Paginable rendering

Tags: sxa

I am trying to add pagination component with custom paginable controler but it shows "There is no list on the page with the same signature" although both pagination component and paginable rendering share the same list signature.

Is there any steps that should be done so that the pagination works with controller rendering?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start when you are creating your custom paginable rendering is to investigate Page Content feature. This is the place where Page List rendering is located - it's supporting pagination.

Few things which have to be done:

- controller - you controller should inherit from `PaginableController` and provide pagination configuration. Just investigate `PageListController`, everything is there
- repository - your repository which is providing model should take into account how many elements skip and how many take for a certain page (those are params from pagination configuration provided by the controller)
- config entry - this is probably what you are missing, take a look at `Sitecore.XA.Feature.PageContent.config` file of (`Sitecore.XA.Feature.Media.config`), you will find there `<paginationEnabledRenderings>` element - simply put there your rendering id

This is how this config entry looks for Page List:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <experienceAccelerator>

      ...

      <!-- List of renderings that support pagination. -->
      <paginationEnabledRenderings>
        <rendering id="{2E991AA4-4B08-43D2-AD2B-17C11E69A499}" name="Page List"/>
      </paginationEnabledRenderings>

      ...

    </experienceAccelerator>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your updates, it worked after adding configuration. Could you please provide me with reference or documentation that i can refer to if i faced any future issues like this missing configuration?

Comment: Basically here is the place to start: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator. I know, a lot of topics are missing there but we are working on this.